# Tmux help - keeping the session open after script completion

Tags: tmux

I want to run one command to start tmux AND run a command, but I want the tmux session to stay open after the command finishes in tmux. The command I'm currently using is:`tmux new-session -d -s minecraft_server 'bash /home/ratus5/script.sh'`

This starts a session and runs the script, but exits after the script finishes, but I need to to stay open.

Comment: See this example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278076/is-it-possible-to-start-tmux-visible-session

Comment: Just add another command, `'bash /home/ratus5/script.sh;exec bash -i'`